# Passing XMLdata from uitableviewcontroller to a viewcontroller in another storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsxmlparser, uitableview

i am trying to pass my xml fetched data of a string from a uitableviewcontroller1 to another nsstring in another viewcontroller2 but when i nslog nsstring in viewcontroller it shows NULL. here is my code. Thanks

**UiTableViewController1.h**

```
ViewController2 *aOnly;
```

**UiTableViewController1.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self sendID];
    aOnly = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    aOnly.audioOnly = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]xmls_type];

}
```

**ViewController2.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *audioOnly;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *audioOnly;

@end
```

**ViewController2.m**

```
@synthesize audioOnly;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"output is %@", audioOnly);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is 2 instances of your 2nd viewController:

One created by hand (alloc/init)

One created by the Storyboard.

The one created by the Storyboard is unaffected by your code.

Comment: yes actually my ViewController2 is in another StoryBoard.

Comment: So store your data in an external singleton (for example) then fetch it from that singleton in viewDidLoad.

Comment: can you explain me further how can i do that with my code. Thanks